# ColorClip throws error when using the 'color' argument

Tags: python, moviepy

I'm trying to create a video clip with a certain color:

```
clip = ColorClip(size=(460, 380), color=[122, 12, 54])
```

However, when I run my script I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'color'
```

It works fine when I omit the color argument, it just renders a black video clip.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: run `help(ColorClip)` to get information about it's call signature, it may need to be passed as a positional only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seams there is some bug in code and it expects name `col=` instead of `color=`

---

**BTW:** I send issue to author - https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/366

Comment: Thanks! That was it. 

Comment: BTW: I send issue to author - https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/issues/366